# Pale/Opaque font color

Tags: fonts, colors

I don't know what I did but all of a sudden certain fonts (Courier, I believe) displayed on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine became kind of pale/opaque, which makes coding very challenging. See the below screenshot-examples:

[Dymola Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8zIz.png)

[Some Latex code, I found in the web (screenshot from Firefox)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXFj7.png)

I noticed the issue when opening Dymola to work on some Modelica code, but this seems to be a system wide thing (I tried it also in LibreOffice). Most other displayed fonts are just fine. Is there anything I can do about it?

(Sorry for the links. As I am new here, they won't let me post pictures directly...)

**Edit**

I disabled the two Courier fonts using font-manager which resulted in Dymola showing code in another font and fine colors. So as a question remains: How can I fix Courier?